# how to create an application which allows user to free hand drawing?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am new to iPad application development.

I have task to develop an application like  [iDesk](http://tentouchapps.com/idesk) application I don't know how to start with application.

this application has 1. Freehand Drawing 2. Shape Recognition & much more functionality. but I don't know how to start with this app. 
please help me.

provide some details about that how to create this app. i think this app is created from openGL. please provide me some samples if it is possible.

please help me.

I have posted new question about this topic [New Question for this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292629/how-to-detect-user-draw-rectangle-ellipse-or-other-geometric-things-in-iphone-s)

please help me with this.

Comment: Urhm, I'm afraid you're asking us to tell you how to write your app. Go look up some tutorials. Learn more about app development. If you don't know how to start something, that's a good sign you don't know enough to be doing it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS open source drawing application source code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121184/ios-open-source-drawing-application-source-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following i have used it earlier. It will work definately:-

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        [drawImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"white" ofType:@"png"]]];
        return;
    }

    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    lastPoint.y -= 20;

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    mouseSwiped = YES;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.drawImage];
    currentPoint.y -= 20;

    NSLog(@"current Point is x: %d, y: %d",currentPoint.x,currentPoint.y);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.drawImage.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.drawImage.frame.size.width, self.drawImage.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.5, 0.6, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a UIView subclass I use for drawing. I can't remember where I sourced it so if anyone recognises the code please give credit to the original programmer:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> 



 @interface SignatureView : UIView {
       UIImage *myPic;
   }

   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myDrawing;
   @property (nonatomic) BOOL canDraw;

   - (void) drawPic:(UIImage*)thisPic;
   - (void) cancelDrawing;
   - (UIImage*) collectSignature;

   @end




    #import "SignatureView.h"

    @implementation SignatureView

    @synthesize canDraw, myDrawing;

    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
    {
    //round the corners
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;

    float newHeight;
    float newWidth;
    if (!myDrawing) 
        myDrawing = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    if (myPic != NULL) 
    {
        float ratio = myPic.size.height/460;
        if (myPic.size.width/320 > ratio) 
        {
            ratio = myPic.size.width/320;
        }
        newHeight = myPic.size.height/ratio;
        newWidth = myPic.size.width/ratio;
        [myPic drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0, newWidth, newHeight)];
    }
    if ([myDrawing count] > 0) 
    {
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 5);
        for (int i = 0; i < [myDrawing count]; i++) 
        {
            NSArray *thisArray = [myDrawing objectAtIndex:i];
            if ([thisArray count] > 2) 
            {
                float thisX = [[thisArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
                float thisY = [[thisArray objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
                CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
                CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, thisX, thisY);
                for (int j = 2; j < [thisArray count] ; j+=2) 
                {
                    thisX = [[thisArray objectAtIndex:j] floatValue];
                    thisY = [[thisArray objectAtIndex:j+1] floatValue];
                    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, thisX,thisY);
                }
                CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)drawPic:(UIImage *)thisPic 
{
    myPic = thisPic;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    [myDrawing addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4]]; //memory leak
    CGPoint curPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    [[myDrawing lastObject] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:curPoint.x]]; //memory leak
    [[myDrawing lastObject] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:curPoint.y]]; //memory leak
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    CGPoint curPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    [[myDrawing lastObject] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:curPoint.x]]; //memory leak
    [[myDrawing lastObject] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:curPoint.y]]; //memory leak
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    CGPoint curPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    [[myDrawing lastObject] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:curPoint.x]];
    [[myDrawing lastObject] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:curPoint.y]];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)cancelDrawing 
{
    [myDrawing removeAllObjects];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (UIImage *)collectSignature
{
    //take screenshot
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return viewImage;
}

@end
```