# what is the best way to provide free draw hand writing in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, drawing, quartz-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to create an application which allows user to free hand drawing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207913/how-to-create-an-application-which-allows-user-to-free-hand-drawing)

I am trying to implement free hand writing on a view. I used some of the existing code, which is working well when user is writing very slow, where as if the user writes very fast it's not recognizing all the points(what ever the points are touched by the user).
my sample code is here

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        mouseSwiped = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    currentPoint.y -= 20;


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
    if (mode == DrawingModePen) {
        NSLog(@"drawing");
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [_drawingPenColor CGColor]);
    }
    else {
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);

        CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());


        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextClearRect (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y, 20, 20));
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

        NSLog(@"clearing");
            }
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;

    mouseMoved++;

    if (mouseMoved == 10) {
        mouseMoved = 0;
    }
}
```

is there any other way to implement this? I have seen GLPaint provided by apple. It is also not much useful more over its causing memory warnings in my app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i need Freehand Drawing only nothing more,what ever the link you provided which is helpful some extent and i will try to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the Apple developers tutorial [GLPaint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html). It may a help a lot for the beginners in developing paint application.