# how to detect user draw rectangle, ellipse or other geometric things in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have task to develop an application like iDesk. i have already post a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207913/how-to-create-an-application-which-allows-user-to-free-hand-drawing)
on stackoverflow i have find a way how to recognize user draw a circle [detecting circle](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/04/detecting-circle-gesture.html)

now i want to gesture all geometric like ellipse,rectangle or others.

i have not any idea about it please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be very familiar with "Core Graphics" framework for drawing .

[Drawing Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html)

[Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

For shape recognition you need some math master or some C library (if there is such library) , that is really difficult task .